# Telerik's OpenAccess ORM and DevArt's dotConnect for Oracle

Tags: .net, telerik, devart, dotconnect, openaccess

Has anyone tried to connect to an Oracle DB using DevArt's `dotConnect` data provider among with `OpenAccess` ?

`OpenAccess` works excellent with `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`, but how about `dotConnect`?

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Devart dotConnect driver is not currently supported by OpenAccess. Why would you use the dot connector instead of the Oracle.DataAccess.Client anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @ScorpiAS. My company purchased DevArt's dotConnect, and, from what my team leader said, it has better performances than Oracle.DataAccess.Client. Moreover, dotConnect for Oracle can be used without Oracle Client Software installed. A little comparison that he gave me:
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/comparingproviders.html

Comment: You can also use odp.net with no client(almost) installed now by using instant client.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had any sucess with this? I also have just bought Devart's dotConnect and I am looking to use Telerik's Open ORM, but before I go and buy the Telerik pack I would like to know if this can be achieved.

Also dotConnect is far better than using ODP.Net or Oracle.DataAccess, the direct access gives you a completely client free way of access the database over TCP/IP and if you go through the client (which you can still do with dotConnect) you get a lot more functionality and entity framework support that just isn't available with ODP.Net or Oracle.DataAccess.

Cheers,

Andy

Comment: Unfortunately, no. At that time, we needed a fast and stable solution, so we have chosen only DevArt products (which are great, btw). If your budget permits, opt out for full DevArt support. Don't make your life harder by choosing incompatible products from different companies! Cheers!